# Display Outlook profile picture

Tags: outlook, outlook-restapi

Is there any way to get the  outlook profile picture using access_token ?
I have also tried with URL :

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('user_id')/photo
```

But it is asking for username and password. Even  when I give outlook credentials I couldnt fetch the picture. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct format of the request is the following:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('abc@abc.com')/photo/$value
```